# Grid-search for a multi-output regression task using Scikit-learn's API

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, grid-search, lightgbm, multi-output

I'm trying to make a model for a multi-output regression task where $y=(y_1, y_2,..., y_n)$ is a vector rather than a single scalar. I am using Scikit-learn's `MultiOutputRegressor` method to train and make a model for each $y_i \in y$ separately. My code looks like this:

```
base_learner = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor(random_state=seed)
estimator = MultiOutputRegressor(regressor)

grid = {
    # hyperpramters to check
    # ...
    # 'random_state': [500],
    'n_estimators': [100, 500],
    'num_leaves': [15, 31, 63],
    'max_depth': [8, 10],
    # 'min_data_in_leaf': [15, 25],
    'feature_fraction': [0.3, 0.4],
    'bagging_fraction': [0.4, 0.5],
    # 'bagging_freq': [100, 200, 400],
    "n_jobs": [-1],
    "verbose": [-1]
}

gs = GridSearchCV(base_learner, param_grid=grid, scoring=my_custom_score, cv=10)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

As you can see, the base-learner for each $y_i$ is of type `lightgbm.LGBMRegressor`. (By base-learner, I mean each individual leaner used to learn and predict each $y_i$.) I want to do a grid search to pick the best hyperparameters for each base-learner. But I don't know how to pass the list of hyperparameters in the `grid` variable to the base learners that are wrapped in `MultiOutputRegressor`. When I run the shown code above, I get the following error:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion about how to pass hyperparameters to individual base-learners when one uses `MultiOutputRegressor` API? (Based on what I see in the error, `MultiOutputRegressor` itself only takes two parameters which are mainly for a using a leaner not passing hyperparameters to the underlying learners.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant `GridSearchCV(estimator ...`, otherwise there's no wrapping here.
You'll need to supply a prefix:

```
'estimator__n_estimators': [100, 500],
'estimator__bagging_fraction': [0.4, 0.5],
```

and so on.